# A dependent and discrete version of the Komlós-Major-Tusnády theorem

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, levy-processes

The well-known Komlós-Major-Tusnády approximation gives sharp speed of convergence of a uniform empirical process to a Brownian bridge. Here I am considering how to approach a similar problem with dependence and discretization. Specifically, suppose we uniformly choose $m$ numbers from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ ($n > m$) at random and color these $m$ numbers red. Then we consider
$$F(t) = \sqrt{m} \left[\frac{\#\{1 \le i \le \lfloor tn \rfloor: i \text{ is colored red}\}}{m} - t \right].$$

Intuitively, $F(t)$ should also converge weakly to a Brownian bridge. However, due to dependence caused by sampling without replacement and discretization because of a finite $N$, the KMT theorem can not apply directly here.

> **Question.** Is there any generalization that gives the convergence speed of this $F(t)$ to a Brownian bridge for any finite $m$ and $n$?

Comment: What do you have in mind for the relative sizes of $m$ and $n$? Are you interested in the case where they're comparable or are you more thinking about $n\gg m$?

Comment: Yes I am mostly interested in the case $n \gg m$. In other words, we may ignore the discretization brought by a finite $n$ for the time being.